# ternary operator and goto in c, executing both

Tags: c, goto, conditional-operator

I'm trying to implement goto in ternary operator:

So here is what I'm doing :

```
(a<5 && done==0) ? ({goto dd;}) : ({goto ee;});
```

With those braces I'm trying to convert statement into expression.

The problem is, both labels are being executed. Why?

Here's the code ([Ideone link](https://ideone.com/W2gbU4)):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0,sum=0;
    int done=0;

    (a<5 && done==0) ? ({goto dd;}) : ({goto ee;});

    dd:
        printf("%d - %d -- %d\n",a,sum,done);
        ++a,sum+=a;
    ee:
        printf("done\n");
        done=1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't really have statements in a ternary expression (no matter what extensions your compiler have), only expressions. That's because as an expression, it must return a value.

Comment: How would you know if only the first was executed? If you reach `dd` you will also execute what is located after `ee`.

Comment: Operators are used to evaluate expressions. If you really try hard to abuse them and stick a finger in your eye, don't be surprised if it hurts.

Comment: And besides, even if `goto` is something one should use (which you really shouldn't), ternary expressions tend to make code harder to read, understand and maintain. Default to a plain `if` *statement* instead.

Comment: Labels are just labels, they don't define a code block. Execution doesn't jump around the code under `ee:` just because you had a `goto dd;`. It'll start at `dd:` and keep going until it hits some other `goto` or `return` or something.

Comment: Where are the dd and ee labels?

Comment: Please edit your post and copy the code into it. Don't make us follow an external link to find your code. (Oh, Marco beat you to it.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: You can have statements in an expression with that GCC extension. It is a statement-expression extension.

Comment: MSVC: the code won't even compile: 10 errors.

Comment: @r3mainer I was just about to write precisely that.

Comment: Besides `goto` and ternary expressions, putting multiple expressions separated by comma as single statements is *also* a bad habit. Where did you find this code? If you made it yourself, then please stop, and try to learn away those bad habits.

Comment: Is there something wrong with a nice simple `if(){...}` ?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Looking at the code in the question, it appears OP is exploring and learning how this GCC extension works, not necessarily building it into production code. Students ought to try all sorts of weird experiments; it helps them learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After `goto dd;`, program control jumps to the `dd` label, executes the statements there, and continues to the statements following the `ee` label. To make control not flow from the statements after the `dd` label to the statements after the `ee` label, you must insert a `return` statement or other jump statement.

`({goto dd;})` is a terrible abuse of the GCC statement-expression extension. Do not use that code.

Answer (score -1):

Ternary operator returns a value. It does not execute the statement. Hence your goto's are not getting executed.

Comment: The gotos are executed

Comment: One of the gotos is executed. [According to the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) "Jumping out of a statement expression is permitted, but if the statement expression is part of a larger expression then it is unspecified which other subexpressions of that expression have been evaluated except where the language definition requires certain subexpressions to be evaluated before or after the statement expression."